Rules for tensor product of H-S operators
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space, let $\mathcal{S}$ be the Hilbert space of H-S operators from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H},$ and let $A,B,C,D\in\mathcal{S}.$
Are their certain calculation rules for the tensor product operator $\otimes_\mathcal{S}\colon\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathcal{S}$ ? This operator is for given operators $A, B$ defined as $(A\otimes_{\mathcal{S}}B)(x) = \langle A, x\rangle_{\mathcal{S}}B,$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_{\mathcal{S}}$ denotes the inner product of the space of H-S operators.
E.g. are their certain rules how to write the following expressions differently?
\begin{align}
(A\circ B \circ C)\otimes_{\mathcal{S}}D,\qquad (1)\\
A\otimes_{\mathcal{S}}(B\circ C \circ D).\qquad (2)
\end{align}
The background for this question is that I would like to express the following expected value
$$
E(X\otimes_{\mathcal{S}}(A\circ Y\circ B))
$$
with $X,Y$ being random and $A,B$ deterministic H-S operators, in relation to the cross-covariance operator $E(X\otimes_{\mathcal{S}}Y).$
